# Message blocks not working for (customer/session) Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am writing in controller

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess($hlp->__('Vendor registered successfully.'));
```

In my phtml Page

```
echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml()
```

But it's not showing success message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo $this->getMessagesBlock()` returns by default the messages of `core/session` as you can see in `\Mage_Core_Model_Layout::getMessagesBlock`.

Try to use `$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');` in your controller after `$this->loadLayout()` and before `$this->renderLayout()`.